# SQL Server : insert identity

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have 2 tables `ProductSize` and `Product`.

**Product** table:

```
ProductID   ProductCode  ProductSizeID
```

**Product Size** table:

```
ProductSizeID   PackperCase    ItemsperCase    ItemSize
```

I have a stored procedure which populates both these tables, however I can't populate the `Products` table without populating the `Product Size` table (as I need the `productsizeID`).

How can I tackle this?

I need something which shows the last ID I just inserted into the `Productsize` table. The stored procedure inserts 1 record at a time, but I don't really want to use `MAX()` to get the ID because other things may be going on in the database.

Comment: If the sproc inserts 1 record at a time, why can't you use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190315.aspx) to get the value that you just inserted?

Comment: Thank you, I used his SELECT ID2 = SCOPE_IDENTITY() Print ID2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first insert the row into `ProductSize` and get the ID back:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ProductSize(PackPerCase, ItemsPerCase, ItemSize)
VALUES( ....., ....., .....);

DECLARE @NewID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

and then use that in your second insert into the `Products` table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Products(ProductCode, ProductSizeID)
VALUES( ....., @NewID);
```

and you're done!